# how to show subscript characters in a qlabel

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to show subscripts in a QtGui.QLabel using python 3.4, qt 4.8, and pyqt 4.11.  In the code sample below i have a function `_subscripter` that takes an integer and returns a string subscript i.e.

```
_subscripter(13)
Out[8]: '₁₃'
```

I want the label just show the subscript '₁₃' however it does not recognize that (see image below).  any help appreciated.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from sys import argv, exit

def _subscripter(n):
    digits = len(str(n))
    s = ''
    for i in range(digits):
        s += chr(0x2080 + int(str(n)[i]))
    return s

def start_app():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)
    window = QtGui.QLabel(_subscripter(13))
    window.show()
    window.activateWindow()
    exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__': start_app()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a rich text label instead?

You could do this

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from sys import argv, exit

def start_app():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)
    window = QtGui.QLabel('Some text<sub>13</sub>')
    window.show()
    window.activateWindow()
    exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_app()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `QChar` in place of `chr` should work.

```
def _subscripter(n):
    digits = len(str(n))
    s = QtCore.QChar()
    for i in range(digits):
        s += QtCore.QChar(0x2080 + int(str(n)[i]))
    return s
```

Comment: Looks like i'm missing that class in my setup... ``QtCore.QChar`` throws an attribute error.. Maybe that has something to do with the issue to begin with?  I thought with python 3.4 ``QChar`` and ``QString`` aren't needed

Comment: You may be right, I tested this with python 2.7 as I don't have python 3 installed on my system. On 2.7 I can also just use `unichr` to get the job done. `chr` in python 3 is supposed to do the same thing, so I'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: @user3419537. By default, PyQt4 only provides the `QString` and `QChar` classes for Python 2, not Python 3. For the latter, those classes are automatically mapped to python string objects.